# Outlook, setting MailItem.BillingInformation field when sending emails

Tags: c#, outlook

I've been struggling with integration with Outlook. I want to store a unique ID from my application in either the BillingInformation or Mileage properties in an Outlook Mail Item. While the integration seems to work on my application side, Outlook does not seem to capture the information. Upon modifying the Outlook Message form, at Display time before Send, to include the BillingInformation field, I was able to see the value, but only then, and not for any subsequent attempts. All of my attempts to permanently modify the Message form have proven fruitless. I would appreciate any assistance. Code is below.

```
         //Instantiate the Outlook Email object
        Outlook.Application olApp = new Outlook.Application();
        Outlook.MailItem eMail = olApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem) as Outlook.MailItem;

        // Define and map Email data
        eMail.Subject = row.Name;
        eMail.Body = row.Notes;
        string act = row.ActivityID.ToString();
        eMail.BillingInformation = act;
```

Comment: Are you trying to make sure BillingInformation will appear on the receiving side?

Comment: Yes. I want the ID from my app to end up in a field in an outlook email. This works easily and well for outlook contacts and appointments.

Answer (score 1):

It will only work if the message is never converted to MIME format - that means the messages must either be sent between 2 Exchange mailboxes in the same domain or it must be sent in the RTF format (the infamous winmail.dat - it preserves all MAPI specific properties).

You can add a MIME header to the outgoing email by setting a named property in the PS_INTERNET_HEADERS namespace using `MailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty` (e.g. `MailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/X-Test", "MyValue")`). You can then read the property on the receiving side by reading the PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS property (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001F`) using `MailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty`.

Comment: Thanks. How do I know if/when/where my email is converted to MIME format?

Comment: If you send through SMTP or through Exchange to a recipient from another Exchange domain, your message will be converted to MIME unless a special property (useTnef) is set.